# Changed website from http to https: what to do in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, redirects, sitemap

So now I have two domains in my Webmaster Tools, as I have migrated to HTTPS. Migration here means that I have enabled HTTPS and enforced it, that's it.

My question: should I do something in `Webmaster tools`? I was thinking of re-submitting my *sitemap with HTTPS*, but wouldn't that be a `duplicate` then? And what about redirecting? Should I still redirect everything via `301`?

Anyone who can explain/elaborate? I am asking, because I do not want that my SEO gets affected negatively and can't find a good source where everything is answered properly.

Comment: What used to be Google Webmaster Tools is now Google Search Console and has been for a couple years.

Answer (score 1):

On the **Webmaster tools website**, you should:

- Delete the old site (without http)
- Add the new site (with https)
- Recheck every configuration
- Send your new sitemap (it should be generating HTTPS urls at this
  point).

However, prior to doing all this, you should do the following on **your site**:

- Make sure every page is redirecting correctly using a 301 code from
  the http to the https site
- Making sure your web pages display a canonical tag informing the
  search engines which is the actual, current page.

If you don't do the redirect and/or canonical you might be seen as duplicate and be penalized for it. The best approach is to do both.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the old site. In fact you may want to verify all variants. e.g. with and without www. That way you can see if the transition is going smoothly. There is no duplicate penalty but I'd still do the rest suggested by Luis to minimise any issues that duplication can cause.